# Varnish Redirect Subfolder Homepage to :8080 in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I am using Apache and Varnish installed. I have a problem when accessing my subfolder homepage without trailing slash at the end of URL, it redirect to :8080.

That will redirect to http://www.example.com:8080/subfolder/

But if I access http://www.example.com/subfolder/
It loads just fine.

I read to resolve this issue for NGINX user is only add `port_in_redirect off;`

How to resolve it in Apache?

Comment: Without including the configuration files or at least the relevant sections, diagnosing the problem is almost pure guesswork. A missing proxypassreverse directive would be one guess in Apache though.

Comment: Thanks HBruijn. I tried your suggestion to add proxypassreverse. It  works but then if I accessing other pages, it 503 service unavailable. Only home page normal.